# Not able to delete yammer comment using powershell

Tags: powershell, office365, yammer

```
$url= "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/‍4234234234"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Delete -Headers $UserHeaders
```

This gives me below error on powershell

`Invoke-WebRequest` :

> This 500 error rarely happens, but even Yammer’s https don’t deliver
>   sometimes.  The team’s working on it. In the meantime, go to Yammer. 
>   At C:\Chetan\codes\test2.ps1:32 char:9
>   +         Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $DeleteYamComment -Method Delete -Head ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 500 error indicates there was a problem on the server side that you as the caller have no control over. The error text the Yammer API returned says as much. There's likely nothing you can do until the Yammer team fixes their servers.